# How to initialize an array inside a structure?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, pointer-to-array

I have a structure defined as

```
struct new{
  int x;
  int y;
  unsigned char *array;
};
```

where I want array to be an array which is initialized dynamically based on user input. Inside main function:

```
struct new *sbi;
sbi->array = (unsigned char*)malloc(16 * sizeof(unsigned char));

      for(i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
          sbi->array[i] = 0;
        }

      for(i=0; i<16; i++)
        printf("Data in array = %u\n", (unsigned int)sbi->array[i]);
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong with the malloc but I am not getting it - it just keeps giving segmentation fault.

Comment: where does `sbi` point to, right before the `malloc`? In your snippet, `sbi` has not been initialized or assigned a value.

Comment: ALso `new` is a keyword in C++. You may want to avoid that identifier if your code has a chance of ever being translated to that language :-)

Comment: Title should read "How to initialize a pointer to a structure?"

Comment: aha my bad! I didn't initialize sbi. Got it.

Comment: `array` is a pointer to `char`, not an array. Standard warning: Do **not** cast `void *` (as returned by `malloc()`) to other pointers.

Comment: @pmg: While I agree about not using `new` for an identifier, C code using malloc the proper way will not translate properly in C++ without changes anyway - left along that one should use OOP techniques in an OOPL anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring sbi as a pointer to struct new, but never allocating memory to it.  Try this:

```
struct new *sbi;
sbi = malloc(sizeof(struct new));
```

Also, don't cast the results of malloc, as that can mask other errors, and don't forget to check the return value of malloc.

Comment: And please check the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: @OP: Don't forget to free the memory after.